# Migrating our MVC web app user management to Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have a MVC Web application that has its own local SQL database. We want to migrate user management of our application to "single sign on" with Azure AD B2C.
Currently we have 3 types of users who can access our web application through the browser (admin, customer1 and customer2). Based on each type of user, we display home page customised for that user type.

We want to get the user information from Azure (included in the ID Token received from Azure) and 
then at our end based on the user type of that user we display relevant information to that user.

My question: 
How to move these 3 types of users to Azure? Should we create 3 different SignIn policies for each user types?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) for a user object, so that when you migrate the user into Azure AD B2C, you can add a value in the custom attribute for each user (admin, customer1, customer2). You can then get that custom attribute as a claim in the token, and so based on that your app can show the relevant homepage.